# How can i have Normalizer method?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to Normalize a entry Persian list. But i can not achieve to my ideal result.
The function delete the unnecessary character from text and word.

```
normal = ["&quot;","&raquo;","http://","www.",
"cloob","instagram","https://","t.me","هه","اا","یی","خخ","وو",
"مم","ـــ","؟؟","!!",":)",":((",":))",
"-*","=))","&zwnj;","&hellip;","&infin;","غغ","جج",":-*","نن","&rlm;",
"...","&nbsp;","دد",":-*","@};-","کک"]

def normalizer(mylst):
n = ""
retrnlst = []
for snt in mylst:
    #print(snt)
    for n in normal:
        for n in snt:
            if (n=="http://"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "http:// ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="www."):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "www. ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="cloob"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "cloob ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="instagram"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "instagram ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="https://"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "https:// ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="t.me"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "t.me ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="هه"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "ه")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="اا"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "ا")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="يي"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "ي")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="خخ"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "خ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="وو"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "و")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="مم"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "م")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="غغ"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "غ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="نن"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "ن")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="دد"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "د")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="کک"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "ک")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="گگ"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "گ")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="فف"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "ف")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            elif (n=="جج"):
                snt = snt.replace(n, "ج")
                retrnlst.append(snt)
            else:
                snt = snt.replace(j, "")  
          retrnlst.append(snt)
return retrnlst

##my input string    
var="منننننننن دوستتتتتتتتت دااااااااارممممممممممممم عشقم http://&raquo;"
var=normalizer(var)
print(var)
```

Ideal result is:" http:// من دوست دارم عشقم"
But this is the result of code:

> ['م', 'ن', 'ن', 'ن', 'ن', 'ن', 'ن', 'ن', 'ن', ' ', 'د', 'و', 'س', 'ت', 'ت', 'ت', 'ت', 'ت', 'ت', 'ت', 'ت', 'ت', ' ', 'د', 'ا', 'ا', 'ا', 'ا', 'ا', 'ا', 'ا', 'ا', 'ا', 'ر', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', 'م', ' ', 'ع', 'ش', 'ق', 'م', ' ', ' ', 'h', 't', 't', 'p', ':', '/', '/', 'w', 'w', 'w', '.', '&', 'r', 'a', 'q', 'u', 'o', ';']

Comment: Add the input string sample and what you want to as output at the end of your question

Comment: variable var is my input-test string.@gaurav

Comment: This is because your algorithm divide the string list into character list in order it receive string. Nothing else it does, it receive http at last so it is returning http:// at last, I am not able to recognize urdu words but all i understand is you want https:// in first then some urdu words